# toggle function that gradientifies background color

Tags: javascript, jquery

Basically I'm trying to toggle a function that gradually change background color of div. There's a separate script.js file that is responsible for function gradientify() to run.

I'm just not sure what is the logic to toggle a function...

index.html

```
<body>
    <button type="button" id="btn"></button>
    <div style="width: 100px; height: 100px;"></div>
</body>
```

script.js

```
$('#btn').click(function() {
    $('div').toggle(function() {
        $(this).gradientify({
        gradients: [
            { start: [49,76,172], stop: [242,159,191] },
            { start: [255,103,69], stop: [240,154,241] },
            { start: [33,229,241], stop: [235,236,117] }
        ]
    });
    });
});
```

Comment: You probably could do 

        <button onclick="gradientify()">Click me</button>

Comment: that didn't work for me...

Comment: If I understand correctly, `$#toggle` [does not accept a function as the first argument](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/). Generally, it is incorrect to say "toggle a function" regarding Javascript. And finally, without the code of `$#gradientify`, it's impossible to tell what exactly the source of error is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Jquery `toggle` function toggles the visibility of an element. It basically sets the css property `display` to `display: none`. If you want the content inside the "gradientifyied" element to still be visible when you toggle the gradients then you can't use `Jquery.toggle`.

Sadly the gradientify API [doesn't provide any way to cancel the gradients](https://github.com/codefog/jquery-gradientify/blob/master/jquery.gradientify.js#L82) once they are set on an element so the only way to toggle the gradients on an element is to remove it from the DOM all together.

We can create a copy of the clean element before the gradiants are applied and when we want to remove the gradients, we remove the old element from the DOM and insert the copy we kept.

```js
function toggleGradients() {
  var gradientTargetCopy = $( ".gradientTarget" ).clone()
  var gradientsOff = true;
  return function() {
    if (gradientsOff) {
      $('.gradientTarget').gradientify({
        gradients: [
          { start: [49,76,172], stop: [242,159,191] },
          { start: [255,103,69], stop: [240,154,241] },
          { start: [33,229,241], stop: [235,236,117] }
        ]
      });
    } else {
      $('.gradientTarget').remove()
      $('body').append(gradientTargetCopy)
      gradientTargetCopy = $( ".gradientTarget" ).clone()
    }
    gradientsOff = !gradientsOff
  }
}

$('#btn').click(toggleGradients());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://codefog.github.io/jquery-gradientify/jquery.gradientify.min.js"></script>

<body>
    <button type="button" id="btn">Toggle gradients</button>
    <div class="gradientTarget" style="width: 100px; height: 100px;">Hello!</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use plain JavaScript.

```
    var x = 3; //Length of amount of color options you want
var bgcolor_num = Math.floor((Math.random() * x) + 1);
        setInterval(function () {
            if (bgcolor_num === 1) {
                bgcolor = "#FF0000";
                bgcolor_num = 2;
            } else if (bgcolor_num === 2) {
                bgcolor = "#00FF00";
                bgcolor_num = 3;
            } else {
                bgcolor = "#0000FF";
                bgcolor_num = 1;
            }

            document.getElementById('whatever').style.backgroundColor = bg_color;
        }, 12000);
```

What happens is that it defines a variable, x, and randomizes a number from 1 to x. Then, an interval (which runs every 12 seconds; 12,000 milliseconds) determines whether the number, bgcolor_num, is 1, 2, 3, or something else. Remember, the amount of options you have has to equal *x*. If it doesn't, it will run as "else" and will start back at color option #1.

Make sure you have an ID set for your div and reconfigure the part that actually triggers the change!

If you want an example of this happening, you can always go to my website [typrograms.com/RGB.html](https://www.typrograms.com/RGB.html) and right-click, view-source! I use a similar method, and it slowly changes the color.

Comment: This is very good explanation. I have to dig into it a little bit more...Thanks a lot!